# The concept under the hood about "delete" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, del

I create a varibale `temp = [10]`

Then I put `temp` into another list variable `ls`

After that, I use `del temp` to delete the `temp` variable

However, I check `ls` and still find that `[10]` is in `ls`

In my intuition, `ls` should be printed as `[]`, but things don't go like that.

I want to ask the deep concept of `del` in Python and maybe some information of copy by reference and copy by value in Python

My code:

```py
temp = [10]
print('id of temp:', id(temp))

ls = [temp]
print('ls before del:', ls)  # ls before del: [[10]]

del temp
print('ls after del:', ls)  # ls after del: [[10]]
print('id of ls[0]:', id(ls[0]))
```

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: In your case you are just deleting the *name* `temp`, so it becomes an unknown name. You leave the name `ls` intact and it continues to refer to the single element list `[10]` you created on the first line.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes The `__del__` method of what object?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes `del` only removes references (names, ....) to objects, and the `__del__` method is only invoked when the object itself gets destroyed (which happens when there are no more references to it, or it gets garbage collected). So as long as there are other references to an object, a name will be deleted by `del` without `__del__` ever being invoked.

Answer (score -1):

I dont suggest using del on list instead use pop or remove.

**Remove**

```
nums = ['1','2']
# remove '2'
nums.remove('2')
```

output

```
['1']
```

**pop**

```
nums = ['1','2']
# remove with index of 0
nums.pop(0)
```

output

```
['2']
```

**Your Case**

```
firstList = [1]
secondList = [firstList] #[[1]]
print(secondList.pop(0))
#or
print(secondList.remove(firstList))
```

Comment: I know there's a better way to remove the element of the list, but I want to know the detail of "del"